# IP scan help - threads?

Tags: android, multithreading, ping

I'm trying to implement an IP scanner, let's say I have this code:

```
// Background Task: Scan network
class BackgroundScan extends AsyncTask<Void, Icmp_scan_result_params, Void> {

    // Process
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        // Load intervals
        long start_interval = scanner.info.get_network_bounds(false); // Start IP address converted to decimal
        long end_interval = scanner.info.get_network_bounds(true); // End IP address converted to decimal

        // Perform scan - Skip network, broadcast and gateway address:
        for (long ip_decimal=start_interval+1; ip_decimal < end_interval; ip_decimal++) {
            // Skip default gateway
            if (ip_decimal == info.ip_to_long(info.default_gateway)) {
                continue;
            }
            // Convert the IP address to string
            final String ip = info.long_to_ip(ip_decimal);
            // Start and run new thread
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    boolean is_reachable = scanner.icmp_scan(ip);
                    Icmp_scan_result_params _params = new Icmp_scan_result_params(ip, is_reachable);
                    publishProgress(_params);
                }
            }).start();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate (Icmp_scan_result_params... _params) {
         // ...
    }
}
```

Scan method here:

```
public boolean icmp_scan(String ip) {
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
        // Send ping command *ROOT*
        try {
            Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 "+ip);
            int result = p1.waitFor();
            // Positive match
            if (result == 0) {
                return true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

But the problem is that the app crashes, probably because of too many executed threads at once (works fine with 5 threads or so). What is the proper and fastest way how can I implement this, to make sure that the app will always run smoothly on any device? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an async task and a thread from `doInBackground`? `doInBackground` is already on its own thread. You probably don't even need the async task.

You can just use a single thread and call `icmp_scan` inside `run()` while a flag like `threadIsNotStopped` is true. Or if you want to make use of multiple threads, wrap the functionality of `icmp_scan` inside a class implementing `runnable`, passing in a partitioned range of ip addresses, and use an `ExecutorService`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html and http://codetheory.in/android-java-executor-framework/

When you need to update the UI, you can do `onPostExecute` by the following:

```
Handler uiCallback = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
uiCallback.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override public void run() {
    // will run on ui thread
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am faced with the same task of implementing IP scanner. I want to share my solution. The code works for about 2-3 seconds because it pings all 254 ip addresses in parallel. And networkScan() is not blocking UI thread. The result will be written in the UI thread to the activityMainBinding.textView

```
public void networkScan()
{
    String ipFirstPart="192.168.1.";

    final List<Integer> ipList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int cur_ip=1; cur_ip<255 ; cur_ip++) ipList.add(cur_ip);

    List<Callable<Boolean>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i_ip = 0; i_ip < ipList.size(); i_ip++) {
        int final_i_ip = i_ip;
        tasks.add(new Callable<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                return icmp_scan(ipFirstPart + ipList.get(final_i_ip));
            }
        });
    }

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ipList.size());

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("pinger devices");
    handlerThread.start();
    Handler uiCallback = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
    uiCallback.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            List<Future<Boolean>> futures = null;
            try {
                futures = executor.invokeAll(tasks);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e);}

            boolean notOne=true;
            for (int i_ip = 0; i_ip < futures.size(); i_ip++) {
                try {
                    if(futures.get(i_ip).get()) {

                        notOne=false;

                        Handler uiCallback = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                        int finalI_ip = i_ip;
                        uiCallback.post(new Runnable() {
                            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // will run on ui thread
                                activityMainBinding.textView.setText(activityMainBinding.textView.getText()+ " " + ipFirstPart + ipList.get(finalI_ip));
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }
                catch (ExecutionException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
                catch (InterruptedException e) { throw new RuntimeException(e); }
            }

            if(notOne){
                Handler uiCallback = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                uiCallback.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        activityMainBinding.textView.setText("not one was found");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}


public boolean icmp_scan(String ip) {
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        try {
            Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 1 "+ip);
            int result = p1.waitFor();
            // Positive match
            if (result == 0) return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {  }
    }
    return false;
}
```